# Evaluating equations during "new EXlement"

Tags: c#, xml, linq

The snippet below isn't summing the variables `(int)winTemp` and `playerWIn`.  I've verified that both variables are assigned the correct value by printing to screen before calling `createXML()`.  My theory is that you cannot evaluate equations while creating new XELEMENT's.  Can anyone verify this?

```
new XElement("playerWin", (int)winTemp + playerWin),
```

If I do it outside of `XElement`, like the commented lines in `saveXML()`, it works as intended.

- If the file did not exist - Excepted XML output should be Wins=10, Loss=1, Tie=0.
- If the file was existed - Excepted XML output should be Wins=20, Loss=2, Tie=0.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Testing_LINQ_to_XML
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Player p = new Player();
            p.readXML();
            p.toScreen();
            p.saveXML();
            p.readXML();
            p.toScreen();
            p.Exit();
        }
    }

    public class Player
    {
        public string path;
        public string playerName;
        public int playerWin = 10;
        public int playerLoss = 1;
        public int playerTie = 0;
        public int winTemp;
        public int lossTemp;
        public int tieTemp;

        public Player()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter player Name...");
            playerName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("n: " + playerName);
            getPath();
            Console.WriteLine("p: " + path);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public string getPath()
        {
            path = (@"..\XML Saves\" + playerName + ".xml");
            return path;
        }

        public void toScreen()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nYour Record Is:\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Wins:     " + playerWin);
            Console.WriteLine("Losses:   " + playerLoss);
            Console.WriteLine("Ties:     " + playerTie);
        }

        public void saveXML()
        {
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                readXML();
                File.Delete(path);
                //playerWin = (int)winTemp;
                //playerLoss = (int)lossTemp;
                //playerTie = (int)tieTemp;
                createFile();
            }
            else
            {
                createFile();                
            }        
        }

        public void createFile()
        {
                XDeclaration _obj = new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "");
                XNamespace gameSaves = "gameSaves";
                XElement fileNew = new XElement("Root",
                                    new XElement("Player",
                                        new XElement("playerName", playerName),
                                        new XElement("Stats",
                                            new XElement("playerWin", (int)winTemp + playerWin),
                                            new XElement("playerLoss", (int)lossTemp + playerLoss),
                                            new XElement("playerTie", (int)tieTemp + playerTie))));


                fileNew.Save(path);
                Console.WriteLine("Save created: " + path);
        }

        public void readXML()
        {
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                var winTemp = new XElement("playerWin", playerWin);
                var lossTemp = new XElement("playerLoss", playerLoss);
                var tieTemp = new XElement("playerTie", playerTie);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nYou don't have any stats to show yet.  Get playing!!!");
            }

        }

        public void Exit()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

XML output:

```
<Root>
   <Player>
      <playerName>Name</playerName>
      <Stats>
         <playerWin>10</playerWin>
         <playerLoss>1</playerLoss>
         <playerTie>0</playerTie>
      </Stats>
   </Player>
 </Root>
```

Comment: Please add a little more code, like the definition of your variables and what is generated right now and how it differs from what you're expecting. Right now it's quite hard to tell what's wrong.

Comment: And the XML, of course. Basically, we need to be able to reproduce the problem in order to help you.

Comment: Not understandable question - more focused sample and valid question required to help it.

Comment: added this comment to OP rephrasing question.

Comment: The locally scoped winTemp variable is hiding the instance variable (inside readXML() method). Thus winTemp instance variable does not get set at all and holds the default value, i.e. 0.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos   That's it, thank you.  How do I add your comment as the correct answer when I don't have voting controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The locally scoped `winTemp` variable is hiding the instance variable (inside `readXML()` method). Thus `winTemp` instance variable does not get set at all and holds the default value, i.e. 0, by the time of addition.